# ActionListener not being executed for second button in dataGrid component

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, datagrid, actionlistener

I have a dataGrid component that render many objects on the screen at the same time. The image below have a sample with two of these components.

[image]

The button **ADD QUEUE** perform two actions:

1. Execute an actionListener.
2. Opens a dialog window on complete

The button from the left execute correctly. The actionListener is called and the dialog window is opened. The button on the right (and all other buttons if rendered) **does not** execute the actionListener, only open the dialog window.

This is the code to generate the dataGrid

```
    <p:dataGrid var="qmgr" id="qmgrs" value="#{manageApplications.applicationBeingEdited.queueManagers}" columns="2" layout="grid" rows="1" paginator="false" >

    <f:facet name="header">Queue Managers and MQ objects being used by the application #{manageApplications.applicationBeingEdited.name}</f:facet>

    <p:panel header="#{qmgr.queueManagerName}">

        <p:dataTable var="qlocal" value="#{qmgr.queuesList}">
            <p:column headerText="LOCAL QUEUE NAME" sortable="true" sortBy="#{qlocal.name}">
                <h:outputText value="#{qlocal.name}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{manageApplications.selectQueuesToAddToAnExistingApplication(qmgr.queueManagerNameId)}" 
                         oncomplete="PF('dlgAddQueuesToApplication').show();" 
                         update=":j_idt3:addQueuesToApplicationPanel" 
                         value="ADD QUEUE" icon="fa fa-plus">
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:panel>
</p:dataGrid>
```

**This is the bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ManageApplications implements Serializable {

    public void selectQueuesToAddToAnExistingApplication(String queueManagerId) 
    {

        System.out.println("This is the ID being received " + queueManagerId);

     }

     // GETTERS AND SETTERS HERE....
 }
```

**Result**
Left button. When clicked the **output is presented** and the dialog window is opened.
Right button. The output is **not written** and the dialog window is opened.

Debugging also shows that the method is not invoked. If the dataDrid has more than two elements the button works only for the first one. The remaining have the same issue, the actionListener is not being invoked.

Comment: Did you find a solution?